# HTML & PHP Information Table

Tags: php

So i'm hosting servers and trying to make a table displaying the information server name players etc i have a script that displays this but i suck at css, What i'm trying to get is a little like in this website http://echelon.kthx.at/pubbans.php

```
    <?php

include ("BC2Conn.php");

// opens a connection to gameserver
$BC2Conn = new BC2Conn("31.185.143.136", 48888);

if (!$BC2Conn->isConnected()) {
    echo "Connection could not be established. " .
    "To debug, set '-d' as 3rd parameter to new connection.<br />" .
    "<br />" .
    "Example: \$BC2Conn = new BC2Conn(\"127.0.0.1\", 48888, \"-d\");";

    return 0; // stop executing this script
}

// secure login
// $BC2Conn->loginSecure("password");

// unsecure login (not salted)

// some random serverinformation
echo "Servername: " . $BC2Conn->getServerName() . "<br />";
echo "Players: " . $BC2Conn->getCurrentPlayers() . "/" . $BC2Conn->getMaxPlayers() . "<br />";
echo "Playmode: " . $BC2Conn->getCurrentPlaymodeName() . "<br />";
echo "Current Map: " . $BC2Conn->getCurrentMapName() . "<br /><br /><br /><u>Players:</u><br /><br />";

// playerlist
$playerNames = $BC2Conn->getPlayerlistNames();
foreach ($playerNames as $key => $content) {
    if ($BC2Conn->getPlayerClantag($content) != "") {
        echo "[" . $BC2Conn->getPlayerClantag($content) . "]";
    }
    echo " " . $BC2Conn->getPlayername($content) . " - Kills: ";
    echo $BC2Conn->getPlayerKills($content) . " | Deaths: ";
    echo $BC2Conn->getPlayerDeaths($content) . " | Score: ";
    echo $BC2Conn->getPlayerScore($content) . "<br />";
}


// logout
$BC2Conn->logout();
?>
```

Comment: So, is this code already generally working and you just need help with formatting the player list as a table?

Comment: you have the link, inspect the elements with google

Comment: use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) :)

Comment: Yes all the php is working it pings my server giving back the following information like server name: balh blah blah then players then players name with there deaths and score but i want them to them to be in like a table with a label in each section so like Server then under it the name then players under it list of players that kind of thing